# Dates comparision not working on my codeigniter model class

Tags: codeigniter, date

```
$today=date('y-m-d');
$query3 = $this->db->query("SELECT exp_date FROM other_data WHERE id_usr ='$session_id' AND status = 1")->row()->exp_date;

if($query3>=$today){
  $lndate =array(

  'visits' => $query2 + 1 ,
  'login_date' => $today
 );

 $this->db->update('other_data', $lndate);
}
```

Here `exp_date` is a date which is in the same format as `$today(date)`. 
Even `exp_date > today` is false the update statement executes in the model 
function of codeIgniter. But it should not execute when the condition is wrong.
The date format matched with database date.
Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: What are the output of these two variables `$query3` and `$today`?

Comment: $query3 is the date that exist on database and $today is the current date

Comment: Tell me the date format of both variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this

```
$today = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('now')); //Current Date
```

And make date format same as `$today` have like this
If your are getting date from database.

After getting the record from the database

```
$query3 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($query3));
if($query3 >= $today){
   //Condition true
}else{
  //Condition false
}
```

Comment: @polasu Glad to help you.